# Every Potential Combination of a Number from a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

I'm attempting to generate all conceivable combinations of a given number using elements from a list. For instance, when the number is `4` and the list contains `[1, 2]`, there are `3` possible combinations:

`[1, 1, 1, 1] [2, 2] [1, 1, 2]`
I sought assistance from ChatGPT to understand this concept better, but the explanations provided were somewhat challenging, especially for someone new to the topic. My aim is to create a code for this task without relying on external libraries.

Comment: Have you heard of [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)? This is what you need here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic programming to find all possible solutions instead of brute-forcing. Cache is necessary in order to not do the same calculations over and over:

```py
from functools import cache

@cache
def combs(number, nlist):
    if number == 0:
        return {tuple()}

    return {
        (*c, i)
        for i in nlist
        if i <= number
        for c in combs(number - i, nlist)
        if not c or i >= c[-1]  # ensure the tuples remain sorted
    }
```

However, you need to use a `tuple` for the `nlist` argument, since a `list` can't be used with caching.

### Timeit

I used `timeit` to compare my answer to James's answer, and here's the result:

```py
find_combinations(4, (1, 2)): 4.520921999996062 seconds
combs(4, (1, 2)): 0.07833337498595938 seconds
--------------------
find_combinations(4, (1, 1, 2, 2)): 12.320804208982736 seconds
combs(4, (1, 1, 2, 2)): 0.0775450419750996 seconds
--------------------
find_combinations(184, (1,)): 419.7830024160212 seconds
combs(184, (1,)): 0.07226641604211181 seconds
--------------------
find_combinations(184, (1, 3, 5, 9, 100)): DNF
combs(184, (1, 3, 5, 9, 100)): 0.7046534579712898 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this problem by backtracking. Determine the number of counts for each element of the list.

The program below assumes the elements of the list are unique. If they aren't then write a wrapper to make it so!

```
def solve( L, targetSum, solutions, pos, currentSum, counts ):                        # Set counts[pos:] recursively
    if pos >= len( L ): return                                                        # Can't go further
    for j in range( ( targetSum - currentSum ) // L[pos] + 1 ):                                                         # Possible values of counts[pos]
        counts[pos] = j
        test = currentSum + j * L[pos]
        if test == targetSum: solutions.append( counts[:] )                           # Store a solution ...
        else:                 solve( L, targetSum, solutions, pos + 1, test, counts ) # ... or go on to next position
    counts[pos] = 0                                                                   # reset


def combinations( L, targetSum ):
    solutions = []
    counts = [0] * len( L )

    solve( L, targetSum, solutions, 0, 0, counts )
    print( "L = ", L, "     targetSum = ", targetSum, "    # solutions: ", len( solutions ) )
    if len( solutions ) < 10:
        for s in solutions: 
            for i in range( len( s ) ): print( f"{L[i]} " * s[i], end='' )
            print()
    print()


combinations( [ 3, 7 ], 11 )
combinations( [ 1, 2 ], 4 )
combinations( [ 1, 3, 5, 9, 100 ], 184 )
```

Output:

```
L =  [3, 7]      targetSum =  11     # solutions:  0

L =  [1, 2]      targetSum =  4     # solutions:  3
2 2 
1 1 2 
1 1 1 1 

L =  [1, 3, 5, 9, 100]      targetSum =  184     # solutions:  9858
```

Answer (score -1):

You want the numbers from the list to sum to a given number.  You can brute-force the answer by iterating over the possible combinations of numbers with replacement for each number.  The maximum combo size will be `min(number_list) // target`.  I.e. if the target is `7` and the list is `[2,3]`, then the longest sequence of numbers from the list is `7 // 2`, or 3.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

def find_combinations(target, num_list):
    max_size = target // min(num_list)
    for r in range(1, max_size + 1):
        for combo in combinations_with_replacement(num_list, r):
            if sum(combo) == target:
                yield combo
```

Running the code on your example:

```
for combo in find_combinations(4, [1,2]):
    print(combo)

# prints:
(2, 2)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Bruteforcing gives horrible performance for this problem

Comment: @Gugu72, yeah.  It does.  I gave *an* answer. For simple cases, this is fine.